# Is there a way to detect button click in another method?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Like

```
@FXML
void start() {
    // for game loop
    while(!winning) {
       if (attack.clicked()) attack();
       else if (defend.clicked()) defend();
    }
}
```

Can it possible to do this? Thanks.

Comment: That `while-loop` is going to freeze your program.

Comment: Do you have any idea what should I do instead of this?

Comment: If you are trying to do a game loop use [`AnimationTimer`](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835). Some tutorials: [here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835) <- my favorite!, and [here](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.co.uk/) <- a blog by one of the top `JavaFX` users on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assisgn true or false to a flag  when when button click(at the button's click handler method). Your sintax may be different at click handler, but your code like this.

```
private boolean isAttackButtonClicked = false;

public void attackButtonclickHandler(ClickEvent e){
  ...
  isAttackButtonClicked = true;
  ...
}
```